# Configure IIS to allow access to one site by IP address

Tags: dns, multiple-domains, iis

I have IIS 10 set up with multiple sites, all working well.   To troubleshoot some intranet DNS issues I was looking at trying to enable access to any one of the sites via IP address.   I have done this on apache but don't understand how to do this on IIS.

So I would like one of the sites (any) to run on http://192.168.1.222 (example).

Comment: If you want to test that machine is up before DNS is set up, why don't you use `/etc/hosts` (`hosts.txt` on windows)?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - that would work if I had one web directory but by just changing the host file I get a 404 error.   I guess this proves that we are hitting the server but it is hard to convince the non-techs that the site is working fine, they are just having a DNS issue.

Comment: Another trick could be to use temparary subdomains for the new server and have people check it out there.   use `new.example.com` and configure IIS to respond to either that name or the official domain.

Comment: Take a look at bindings as Jalarcon has suggested.  That is how IIS manages multiple sites on on single machine.  You can add the host name to the binding data.

Answer (score 1):

IIS (and other web/application servers) can serve several sites at once from the same IP as long as it can distinguish one site from the others in any request that comes through. To achieve this they should have different IPs or the same IP with at least one domain name associated with it.

However, you can have **just one site** in your server assigned to one IP **without any domain name associated to it**, and it can be matched too when a request to that IP comes through.

So, the only thing you need to do is going to that site in IIS and in the"Bindings" dialog make sure it has the IP assigned and no domain name:

[image]

Before that **make sure no other site in IIS has the same Ip assigned without a domain name** because in that case IIS has no way to know which site should respond to requests in that IP.

That's it!